# Missing texture in cycles, it renders Pink

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

Pink texture like in render view (Cycles).   Im trying to render a wall in Cycles, using Displacement, Bumps and Reflection. Im using self-made pictures from colored image using CrazyBump 1.22. Theese are in order: DISP, OCC, SPEC. I have 2 pictures, one in Node Editor to see inside and second which shows how my render looks like.[image: Node Editor look][image: in Material window you can see purple material]

Comment: Have you checked to see if the textures that you specified are still in the specified folder? Maybe you moved something and need to tell blender where it is again. Pink, as far as I know, means that the texture is missing.

Comment: **Pink means that the texture is not available** Blender cannot find it and it defaults to a very lovely pink to let you know. By default Blender does not store the images used on the scene within the blend file. It could be that the file has been moved to a different folder, or is just not accessible or, if you are rendering on a different computer, the image file was not packed with the blend file.

Answer (score 0):

The color texture in your material is missing. That would be the one plugged into the color slot on your diffuse shader. Click on the file logo on the texture that goes into there and re-find your image. If this doesn't work, save your work, close, and reopen your file. IF this doesn't work, append all your objects into a new file.